# Vue animation unwanted change in div size

Tags: html, css, vue.js, animation, css-animations

I'm making a quiz and I want to add some animation when user move between questions. I'm testing with the fade in and out effect. Below is my code for the animation part. It kinda works. But somehow, when I click on the button, for a split second, the div expand down then shrink backup (see image). I don't know what might have caused this. Would appreciate some insight. Thank you.

```
<transition-group tag="div" name="QBox" mode="out-in">
  <h3 class="Q-text" :key="questionID">{{questionText}}</h3>
  <div class="option" :class="{'selected':option.selected}" v-for ="option in options" @click="nextQ(option.association)" :key="option.text"> {{option.text}} </div>
</transition-group>
```

```
.QBox-enter-active{
  animation: slide-in 1s ease;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to create a sample of your problem on https://sfc.vuejs.org/ and post here.

Comment: @Gerfried cool, i didn’t know this existed. Will give it a go.

Comment: 1. try with `transition` (not `transition-group`) and add a `<div>` wrapper around your elements. Transition-group is mainly meant to animate changes in list elements (order, push,...).
2. I guess it's because you don't have the same amount of questions between slides, so the height is not the same? Try to set a fixed height or something

Comment: Thanks @Kapcash. All questions have the same number of options so it's quite weird that the div expands at all. I can use ```transition``` for the question but I need ```transition-group``` for the options anyway. Assigning the fixed height would resolve the animation glitch but will mess up the div when the window is resized so I'd like to find other methods.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.QBox-enter-active{
  opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: slide-in 0.7s infinite;
    -o-animation: slide-in 0.7s infinite;
    animation: slide-in 0.7s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {opacity: 0.5;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

First, you didn't set a duration for your animation

Second, the change trajectory of your frame is not clear

That's why the [sudden] change

try this

Comment: I set the duration of 1s here ' animation: slide-in 1s ease'. I tried your one and the same thing happened